# jQuery UI confirm dialog doesn't return true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
  $(function ()
  {
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog(
      {
          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          height: 240,
          modal: true,

           buttons: {
              "Delete": function ()
              {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  return true;

              },
              Cancel: function ()
              {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  return false;
              }
          },
          close: function() {
            ;
            }
      });
  });

  function ShowDeleteConfirmation()
  {
      var activeEmelent = document.activeElement;
      if (activeEmelent.innerHTML == 'Delete')
      {
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
        return false;
      }
  }
```

//aspx code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="wecc-grid-link" data-cmd="delete" OnClick="Delete_Click" OnClientClick=" return ShowDeleteConfirmation();"  ></asp:LinkButton>
```

//Server side event

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _deleteClicked = true;
        LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow row = lb.Parent.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        if (row.RowState != (DataControlRowState.Selected | DataControlRowState.Edit) &&
           row.RowState != (DataControlRowState.Alternate | DataControlRowState.Selected | DataControlRowState.Edit))
        {
            Delete(row);
        }
        else
        {
            SetRowState(row.RowIndex, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        }

        gvSaveState.DataSource = this.Data;
        gvSaveState.AllowSorting = true;

        gvSaveState.DataBind();
        lbAddItem.Visible = true;
        lbRefreshData.Visible = true;

    }
```

The dialog pops up when I click on the delete link button in my gridview. But, upon Clicking Delete button in the dialog, it doesn't fire my Server Side click event. I do return a value 'true' when the Delete is clicked.

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: returning from those click events has nothing to do with whether or not your server gets called.

Comment: what is activeElement ?

Comment: @Karthikr: The same link button is being used as a Delete as well as a Cancel depending on two different states. So, I'm checking to see if the LinkButton text is "Delete", only then the dialog box must be show.

Comment: @KevinB: I want it to replicate the behaviour of a simple javascript confirm delete message box. What changes do you suggest then?

Comment: You can't replicate the behavior of a confirm 100% since the confirm blocks the execution of javascript and the jQuery UI dialog cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog prevents the default actions from happening, so you need to submit or perform the action in the `Delete` button function.

So returning `false` or `true` doesn't do what you expect.

You need to add more to this (AJAX to send to the server or something similar)

```
"Delete": function ()
              {
                  <add call to function to send data to server>
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              },
```

Comment: I have updated the code with the server side event too. It does exist but I did not add earlier since the area of concern was the client side script. Look forward to your thoughts.

Comment: The dialog hijacks the onClick event so it doesn't continue when you return true like you are expecting.  You need to make an AJAX call or something in the button functions to send info to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery dialog is essentially asynchronous. The standard confirm() function blocks execution until a result is returned. The jQuery dialog does not stop execution, so showDeleteConfirmation() always returns false, and your jQuery buttons are returning their values to nothing. If you want to use the jQuery dialog, your delete button's function will need to have code that submits the form, maybe by putting some ID in a hidden field and calling click() on a hidden button.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the delete button to Confirm .

for  use this code `"Confirm": function ()`  instead of `"Delete": function ()`